Terraform init tries to install the provider hashicorp/azuredevops when it is microsoft/azuredevops
I'm starting to work on Terraform modules linked to Azure.
Terraform init tries to install the hashicorp/azuredevops provider when it doesn't exist. It's managed by Microsoft under microsoft/azuredevops
Terraform providers tells me that it's the 'wif_devops' module that needs it. Here's the code in question: Azure Repo
I added a provider block clearly indicating that it needs microsoft/azuredevops, but it doesn't work.

Adding the error :
Initializing the backend...
Initializing modules...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/azuread versions matching "2.53.1"...
- Finding hashicorp/random versions matching "3.6.2"...
- Finding microsoft/azuredevops versions matching "1.2.0"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/azuredevops...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "3.113.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/azuread v2.53.1...
- Installed hashicorp/azuread v2.53.1 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/random v3.6.2...
- Installed hashicorp/random v3.6.2 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing microsoft/azuredevops v1.2.0...
- Installed microsoft/azuredevops v1.2.0 (signed by a HashiCorp partner, key ID 6F0B91BDE98478CF)
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v3.113.0...
- Installed hashicorp/azurerm v3.113.0 (signed by HashiCorp)

Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/plugins/signing.html
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azuredevops: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuredevops
│ 
│ Did you intend to use microsoft/azuredevops? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are
│ currently depending on hashicorp/azuredevops, run the following command:
│     terraform providers


Hi @Melean , please share the error screenshot by editing the quession.

Hi @VenkatV, I added the error.

I just tested the same code on my machine, and it's working well. Please check your Terraform version; I'm using Terraform V1.9.0. if you are using lower version, kindly upgraded to latest Version: 1.9.3 here

Hi @VenkatV, I have the same error. I wonder if it's a local cache problem other than in the .terraform directory because I delete it every time. I have to try again from another computer or another session.

Do you mean it's working only after deleting all files in directory or working only in another computer?

No, it doesn't work at all, even if I delete the .terraform. I usually delete it locally and run a terraform init regularly because of bad surprises in the past.

Which version of terraform your using?

Try specifying provider meta-argument on every resource and data source used from this provider:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/resource-provider

Same problem. All modules normally using microsoft/azuredevops use haschicorp/azuredevops. This may be a cache problem as mentioned above : image
